# Cell Reference till the last Row

Tags: excel, vba

Can any one help me on the below code.

I'm trying to find if a cell contains any of the text that are in the given Cell range. And then return the text that is found. And its working fine if i give cell range like B4:B6 but i want it to be dynamic till the last row in B column.

Formula Used in the cell

```
IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/COUNTIF($H2,"*"&Requirement!$B$2:$B$4&"*"),Requirement!$B$2:$B$4),"No Data")
```

VBA Scrpit

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1=_"=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/COUNTIF(RC8,""*""&Requirement!R2C2:R4C2&""*""),Requirement!R2C2:R4C2),""No Data"")"
```

Here instead of `Requirement!$B$2:$B$4`, i want it to be till the last row.

Comment: For situations such as yours, I've always preferred using a dynamic named range. You can see [an example here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830287/how-to-create-a-dynamic-defined-range-in-an-excel-worksheet).

Answer (score 1):

This depends on if you want the last row in the sheet or the last row that contains data. The general solution is relatively simple, you replace

```
"R2C2:R4C2"
```

with

```
"R2C2:R" & Rows.Count & "C2"
```

This provides you with the last row in the sheet. If you want the last row that contains data in column `B`, then use:

```
"R2C2:R" & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row & "C2"
```

Use this to replace all relevant cell references in your code.

Comment: You may also use UsedRange to get the last row of the sheet as follows: "R2C2:R" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count & "C2"

Comment: That would work in some cases. There are cases which will lead to problems however, two examples: 1. The upper rows of the sheet were not used (Although unlikely to happen, this could have significant effects) 2. The data in the different columns has different "lengths" (Probably won't cause a problem, but makes it less accurate)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
Since the reference range is in another sheet i used the sheet name instead of ActiveSheet and it worked.
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/COUNTIF(RC8,""*""&Requirement!R2C2:R" & Sheets("Requirement").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row & "C2&""*""),Requirement!R2C2:R" & Sheets("Requirement").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row & "C2),""No Data"")"